# How to filter XML using FilterFunction in Java 8

Tags: java, xml, filter, java-8

I need to filter an XML file using FilterFuction. I want to show only records with "Count>63". I use Spark. Now my code only show amount of lines with letter a. Probably I should to use List, but I don't know how to use it in Java 8 to filter an XML file. As a result I want to get a list of TagName ("control", "arduino" with Count>63).

**Now my code show only amount of "line with a". But I want to get a list of TagName with Count>63. It will be: "control, arduino, raspberry-pi, motion-planning"** Maybe I should to use splitting.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
<row Id="1" TagName="soccer" Count="7" ExcerptPostId="12371" WikiPostId="12370" />
<row Id="2" TagName="servos" Count="63" ExcerptPostId="186" WikiPostId="185" />
<row Id="3" TagName="control" Count="394" ExcerptPostId="192" WikiPostId="191" />
<row Id="5" TagName="gait" Count="4" ExcerptPostId="12362" WikiPostId="12361" />
<row Id="6" TagName="walk" Count="7" />
<row Id="8" TagName="arduino" Count="401" ExcerptPostId="202" WikiPostId="201" />
<row Id="9" TagName="raspberry-pi" Count="151" ExcerptPostId="307" WikiPostId="306" />
<row Id="10" TagName="motion-planning" Count="104" ExcerptPostId="11370" WikiPostId="11369" />
</tags>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String someFile = "/home/files/Tags.xml";

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple app").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<String> logData = spark.read().textFile(someFile).cache();

    ong numAs = logData.filter((FilterFunction<String>) s -> s.contains("a")).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs);

    spark.stop();
}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: be more descriptive about what are you expecting, what result are you getting currently and what do you want to get instead?. further, please tag the library you're using. spark did you say?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post and tag the library for Spark. Now my code show only amount of "line with a". But I want to get a list of TagName with Count>63. It will be: "control, arduino, raspberry-pi, motion-planning"

Comment: @Aominè maybe I should to use splitting

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you are trying to process the XML by treating it as a sequence of lines, splitting it on newline boundaries. You can't parse XML that way - line endings have no particular significance. (You talk of "records" and "lines" but those are meaningless concepts in the XML world: you need to think of elements and attributes.) From a quick look at Spark, I don't see any XML processing capabilities. So it looks to me as if you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: thank you for your answer, maybe it's wrong but I really want to "process the XML by treating it as a sequence of lines", I know that I can do it using splitting, but I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: No, I wouldn't dream of helping anyone to do something so awful. I've seen far too many people on StackOverflow get themselves into a terrible mess by not parsing XML properly.